# javascript namespace definition self reference

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to define a javascript namespace, but within the namespace i have objects that are extensions of basic classes (using backbone and underscore):

```
namespace = {
    subspace: {
        A: some_class.extend({...}),
        B: A.extend({...})
    }
}
```

but this creates a problem because A is not yet defined. 
What is the best practice in this situation?
furthermore, i have multiple subspaces in this namespace and subsequent ones cannot reference the previous one.

```
namespace = {
    subspace: {
        A: some_class.extend({...}),
        B: A.extend({...})
    },
    subspace2: {
        some_function: function(){
            <how do i create an instance of A for example? > 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply cannot do that directly in JavaScript. You have to use separate statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use helper function to manage it. Here is an implementation from **"JavaScript Patterns"** by **Stoyan Stefanov**.

Consider application global object as `MYAPP`.

and function of adding namespaces:

`MYAPP.namespace('MYAPP.modules.module1')`

and here is example implementation of `namespace` method:

```
MYAPP.namespace = function(ns_string) {
    var parts = ns_string.split('.'),
        parent = MYAPP,
        i;

    if (parts[0] === 'MYAPP') {
        parts = parts.slice(1);
    }

    for (i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
        if(typeof parent[parts[i]] === 'undefined') {
            parent[parts[i]] = {}
        }
        parent = parent[parts[i]];
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Comment: I think that you forget to add `parent = parent[parts[i]]` in for loop.

Comment: @ilyamilosevic, thanks for your attention, yep, forgot this line. Updated answer